# Why is only firefox behaving like I want it to when using PHP?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, browser

### SOLVED: EDITED TO ENCODING -> ENCODE WITH UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM.

Before I started coding php on my site it all looked fine on all browsers. So I made the common beginners mistake to just code all my php stuff in mozilla firefox... and now everything is a mess.

If I remove all the php code everything is back to normal again, but that's not a solution.

**In Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]

*Everything looks the way it should, it's all perfect.*

**In Google Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

- *A margin between the top and the navigation div(position:fixed) has appeared.*
- *The content with posts has ran over the footer*

**In Safari:**

[image: Safari]

- *A margin between the top and the navigation div(position:fixed) has appeared.*
- *The content with posts has ran over the footer*

**And in the worst of them all IE:**

[image]

- *The navigation div is no longer acting like position: fixed*
- *Youtube div is on the bottom of the page*
- *Text is bolder*
- *height has been added on some divs*
- *The jquery slider is not working and there is like a margin-top and bottom on it*

Why is the difference so big between the browsers? Any good explanations? This is very frustrating as I was just about to finish the job.

Comment: Browser display is not affected by php, it is affected by your html and CSS

Comment: 1. Some code? 2. Did you check your html source output if anything is written above your doctype declaration?

Comment: Check that all your tags are closed as it should be

Comment: @DanielM There is nothing written above the doctype..

Comment: I'm removing the PHP tag - There is nothing about PHP here.

Comment: I would recommend that you: (1) validate your HTML with an [online validator](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/direct.html.en), and (2) check your CSS rules to make sure you have margins / paddings set up properly. Every browser has different defaults for those things. Firefox is a terrific browser to do web development work in though; it's fairly strong when it comes to web standards.

Comment: @Yazmat I will check that but I doubt it. Is it any difference running it from my computer with xampp and dropbox and if I am putting it on a actual webserver?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check : This document was successfully checked as HTML5!

Comment: @Nworks there is differences but nothing that affect the display like what you are getting. (note that IE is very known for it's bugs in display and always need special fixes)

Comment: @Nworks for both flat and PHP versions?

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime Can only validate the one with php output as I already have loads of php tags in my original file. But the one with php output in is successfully validating.

Comment: I found the problem! I've been using encode with UTF-8, but should have encode with UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in the HTML that your PHP script outputs, rather than the PHP itself. So i'd look in the outputted source code of your web page and see what's being generated and how it differs from your flat HTML site you had before. The problem is likely missing/broken tags, so run the whole thing (the PHP outputted HTML source code) through the W3C validator and you'll likely spot what part of your PHP script is giving you bad/broken HTML.